# Union All combine 2 tables each one using a different sorting and paging

Tags: sql-server

I'm using MS-SQL 2012 and have 2 tables that contains similar data field types.

I'm writing a stored procedure that needs to get 10 records from Table1 using a **specific sort order** and 10 records from Table2 using a **different sort order**.

I also need to use **paging**

Something like

```
SELECT Field1, Field2, Field3   
  FROM TableAAAA  
ORDER BY FieldSort1 DESC    --> DateTime
OFFSET (@PageIndex-1) * 10 ROWS   
  FETCH NEXT @PageSize ROWS ONLY  

UNION ALL

SELECT Field1, Field2, Field3   
  FROM TableBBBB   
ORDER BY FieldSort2    --> INT
OFFSET (@PageIndex-1) * 10 ROWS   
  FETCH NEXT @PageSize ROWS ONLY
```

If I use a UNION ALL, I can only sort at the end of it so I cannot use the code above.

Comment: You can individually sort both sides of the UNION ALL if you use TOP in each SELECT.   Alternately, you could artificially construct some sort of "SortBy" column that will contain a value that you can logically sort the entire resultset by.

Comment: Top X would not allow me to get the OffSet work properly ...I believe

Comment: Even if you used top 100%?   What if you used CTE's?

Comment: Table1 SortBy is a Date, Table2 is an Int. ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a way (since you know the first one is only going to be page size...

```
WITH t1 AS
(

  SELECT Field1, Field2, Field3, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY FieldSort1) AS outerSort1, 0 as outerSort2
  FROM TableAAAA  
  ORDER BY FieldSort1
  OFFSET (@PageIndex-1) * 10 ROWS   
    FETCH NEXT @PageSize ROWS ONLY  
), t2 AS
(
  SELECT Field1, Field2, Field3, 0 as outerSort1, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY FieldSort2) AS outerSort2   
  FROM TableBBBB   
  ORDER BY FieldSort2
  OFFSET (@PageIndex-1) * 10 ROWS   
    FETCH NEXT @PageSize ROWS ONLY  
)
SELECT Field1, Field2, Field3 FROM T1
UNION ALL
SELECT Field1, Field2, Field3 FROM T2
ORDER BY outerSort1, outerSort2
```

Comment: Why do you need the ORDER BY at the end of the UNION ALL ..if the results are already sorted by the CTE ??

Comment: @SDDeveloper - They may be or they may not be, it is NOT required by the specification of UNION ALL that the results are in order, just they are a UNION.

Comment: Instead of row numbers you could just use the sort columns themselves: `WITH t1 AS (SELECT ... Sort1 = FieldSort1, Sort2 = NULL FROM ...), t2 AS (SELECT ... Sort1 = NULL, Sort2 = FieldSort2 FROM ...) SELECT ... ORDER BY Sort2 ASC, Sort1 DESC;`.

Comment: @AndriyM - very true.  in my original design I did not have two sort columns but tried to merge them.  since I'm not doing that ROW_NUMBER() is technically not needed.  However, there can be some issues with ORDER BY and nulls on some platforms so watch for that.

Comment: Quick question. Is this solution better than using a DECLARE @tmpTbl TABLE and then do inserts into it?

Comment: @SDDeveloper - yes.  With CTE the optimizer will pick how to store the temp data and it is generally better at making those choices than you are.  Also, the syntax on a CTE is simpler so I like it better in almost all cases.  Only need a temp table if you need to run it against multiple queries.

Answer (score 2):

You could use either derived tables or CTEs:

```
WITH cteA AS (
SELECT Field1, Field2, Field3
  FROM TableAAAA  
ORDER BY FieldSort1
OFFSET (@PageIndex-1) * 10 ROWS   
  FETCH NEXT @PageSize ROWS ONLY  
),
cteB AS (
SELECT Field1, Field2, Field3
  FROM TableBBBB   
ORDER BY FieldSort2
OFFSET (@PageIndex-1) * 10 ROWS   
  FETCH NEXT @PageSize ROWS ONLY  
)
SELECT * FROM cteA
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM cteB
```

Comment: The issue is that each table has a "different" SortBy

Comment: I know.  I've never used OFFSET before, so maybe I'm not aware of the interaction with the ORDER BY.  But FieldSort1 can be different from FieldSort2.